# Socket Exception during Load Testing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sockets, exception, load-testing

During load testing in Visual Studio I am deal with such errors:

**The requested address is not valid in its context xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx**

The site is accessible at this adress.

How to decide this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a sign that Network emulation isn't working properly. A quick test is to check your network mix and run a single network type at a time. E.g try running LAN only in the browser mix settings.

Check out this article from Microsoft for more information

[Troubleshooting Network Emulation in Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817099.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for recommend! But how to add different network types without errors during load test?